# M2 Installation got stuck at 64% Magento_CatalogSearch

Tags: magento2

The installation of `magento 2.2.5` got stuck while installing the `Magento_CatalogSearch` module.

I have tried it twice but every time it got stuck at the same point.Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Change in php.ini.

```
max_execution_time = 1800
max_input_time = 1800
memory_limit = 1024M
```

Look for this [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_70pct.html) for further help.